# Proving Inner Product Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $E=C^1 [a,b]$ be the space of all continuously differentiable functions. For $f,g \in E$ define $$ \langle f,g \rangle \ = \ \int_a^b f'(x) \ g'(x) \ dx$$
Is $\langle f,g \rangle$ an inner product space?

I'm just checking the four conditions from Kreyszig pg 129.

I have a few questions. I know the first few conditions are true but I'm unsure of the wording for my justification. Because these are continuously differentiable I do not need to incorporate any sort of measure or Lebesgue integral, correct? So the scalar removes due to properties of the Riemann integral constructed as partial sums? Is this a **real** vector space? The functions are real valued, so is the inner product Hermitian symmetric from this fact?

Comment: If you set the boundary value to be 0, then it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\;f(x)=c=$ a constant, then $\;\langle f,g\rangle=0\;\;\forall\,g\;$ , but $\,f\neq 0\;$ ...